# Is there an efficient way in mongoDB to get a combined result document?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I'm facing an optimisation problem in a project with a mongoDB. I have a collection with the following structure (the IDs are fakes for better readabilty):

**Collection "variables":**

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("001"), "customer": ObjectId("100"), "variable": "a", "value": "2" }
{ "_id": ObjectId("002"), "customer": ObjectId("100"), "variable": "b", "value": "7" }
{ "_id": ObjectId("003"), "customer": ObjectId("100"), "variable": "c", "value": "1" }
{ "_id": ObjectId("004"), "customer": ObjectId("200"), "variable": "a", "value": "5" }
{ "_id": ObjectId("005"), "customer": ObjectId("200"), "variable": "a", "value": "3" }
```

Whenever I want to know all variables and values of a customer, i query for...

```
{ "customer": ObjectId("100") }
```

...to retrieve the appropriate variables:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("001"), "customer": ObjectId("100"), "variable": "a", "value": "2" }
{ "_id": ObjectId("002"), "customer": ObjectId("100"), "variable": "b", "value": "7" }
{ "_id": ObjectId("003"), "customer": ObjectId("100"), "variable": "c", "value": "1" }
```

**Now to my question:** Is it possible to get this result as ONE document instead of many? So my wished result should be something like this:

```
{ "variables": [
      { "variable": "a", "value": "2" }, 
      { "variable": "b", "value": "7" }, 
      { "variable": "c", "value": "1" } 
] }
```

I'm looking forward to your ideas, because I already played a lot with projections and aggregation, but did not find a nice solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is exactly what the `$group` stage is for.

Answer (score 0):

Example Query:

```
db.getCollection('variables').aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$customer',
          entries : {$push: '$$ROOT'}
        },
      },
    ]);
```

this will give you the result your want to achieve.

```
[
{
    "_id" : "100",
    "entries" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "001",
            "customer" : "100",
            "variable" : "a",
            "value" : "2"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "002",
            "customer" : "100",
            "variable" : "b",
            "value" : "7"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "003",
            "customer" : "100",
            "variable" : "c",
            "value" : "1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "200",
    "entries" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "004",
            "customer" : "200",
            "variable" : "a",
            "value" : "5"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "005",
            "customer" : "200",
            "variable" : "a",
            "value" : "3"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. Seems to be the perfect fit.  I will try it out later this day.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks a lot. ☺️